# Typescript with Ember Views

Tags: javascript, ember.js, typescript

I have the following Ember View in Vanilla JS:

```
    App.TextboxView = Ember.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div',
        classNames: ['custom-text-area__child custom-text-area--text'],
        attributeBindings: ['contenteditable'],

        isEditable: true,
        typing: false,

        didInsertElement: function() {
        },

        contenteditable: (function() {
            return this.get('isEditable') ? 'true' : 'false';
        }).property('isEditable')

    )};
```

I am attempting to implement said Ember View in Typescript however:

1. Typescript classes export a function
2. Ember Views expect an object
3. *contenteditable* seems to run due to Embers conventions (somewhere in its lifecycle) and sets the computed property appropriately

How could the *contenteditable* function be converted to work with Typescript?

So far I have stubbed out the following class:

```
export class TextboxView {

  public tagName = 'div';
  public classNames = ['custom-text-area__child custom-text-area--text'];  
  public atttributeBindings = ['contenteditable'];

  public isEditable = true;
  public typing = false;

  constructor() {
      var self = this; 
  }

}
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like I am creating a habit of answering my own questions....

The following implementation works as expected (I definitely tried this but obviously was too quick to assume it didn't work LOL):

```
export class customTextBox {
    public tagName = 'div';
    public classNames = ['custom-text-area__child custom-text-area--text'];
    public attributeBindings = ['contenteditable'];

    public isEditable = true;
    public typing = false;

    public contenteditable = (function () {
        return this.get('isEditable') ? 'true' : 'false';
    }).property('isEditable')

    public keyUp = function(event) {
    }

    public keyDown = function(event) {
    }
}
```